# requests.Session with client certificates and own CA

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, client-certificates, ca

Here is my code

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = os.path.join('/path/to/','ca-own.crt')
s = requests.Session()
s.cert = ('some.crt', 'some.key')

s.get('https://some.site.com')
```

Last instruction returns:

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.site.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))`

With curl:

`curl --cacert ca-own.crt --key some.key --cert some.crt https://some.site.com`

returns normal html code.

How can i make python requests.Session send correct certificates to the endpoint?

**P.S.** The same situation will be if i add the following

```
s.verify = 'some.crt'
```

or

`cat some.crt ca-own.crt > res.crt`

```
s.verify = 'res.crt'
```

**P.P.S.**

`cat some.crt some.key > res.pem`

```
s.cert = "res.pem"
```

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.site.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))`

`cat ca-own.crt some.crt some.key > res.pem`

```
s.cert =  "res.pem"
```

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.site.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(116, '[X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:4067)')))`

Comment: Per https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.request you can pass to `verify` a string being the filepath of the CA certificate to use to verify the server certificate received. For further debugging you might wish to be more precise in giving details of your Python and requests version, and the content of your certificate files as the names are vague. You seem also to mix different things: `verify` is for the client to verify the server certificate, where `.cert` is to have a client send a certificate to a server. Two completely separate and different use cases.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thanks for the answer! I need the server verify me by my client certificates. On the server side there is an nginx with `ssl_client_certificate`.

Answer (score 0):

Above code will work if you put `verify=False` in the GET request, but it's not ideal security wise(Man in the middle attacks) thus you need to add the CA certificate(issuer's certificate) file to the verify parameter. More info [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = "/path/to/issuer's certificate"(CA certificate)

session.get('https://some.site.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What should this pem file contain? Add to `verify` parameter?

Comment: You can even put the cert file, then add the path to verify parameter.

Comment: `s.verify= "some.crt"` returns the same error.

Comment: Can you try with s.cert="some.crt" https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates

Comment: got `Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib`

even if i cat some.crt and some.key > res.pem and `s.cert= "res.pem"` i got `certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: I think you need to inject the local issuer certificate(issuer's PEM file) to the python site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem because python can't find validate the local issuer certificate among the certs it has.

Comment: `cat ca-own.crt >> venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`
and before i manually export specail ENV variable: `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` that point to my CA. Still cannot connect...

Comment: One time I had the same issue while using mkcert(https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert). This will generate certificates for the server, but we need to add mkcert's (issuer) certificate to python's certs file to solves the error

Comment: And how have you solved it?

Comment: Don't add your sever certificates to the session or python cacert.pem. Add local issuer's(which generated your server certificates) CA certificate to the session.verify if that doesn't work, append it to the python's cacert.pem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -
session = requests.Session()

session.verify = "your CA cert"

response = session.get(url, cert=('path of client cert','path of client key'))

session.close()

Comment: Welcome on SO and thank you for your answer! 
Could you edit your answer to format your code? It'll improve its readability :)